# Extract letters from random input lang C

Tags: c

[image]

I'm new here. I started software engineering and I have no knowledge of the **C** language. I did the adding part to the queue, but I cannot separate the foreign values ​​entered. Can you help me with this?

I want to perform the steps in the picture

For example:

Input: **E**)(=*89**y**-*/**u**665%**P**
Output: **EYUP**

My Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max 5
int insq(char queue[max][80], int *rear, char data[80])
{
    if (*rear == max -1)
        return(-1);
    else
    {
        *rear = *rear + 1;
        strcpy(queue[*rear], data);
        return(1);
     }
}
int delq(char queue[max][80], int *front, int *rear, char data[80])
{
    if(*front == *rear)
        return(-1);
    else
    {
        (*front)++;
        strcpy(data, queue[*front]);
        return(1);
     }
 }
 int main()
 {
     char queue[max][80], data[80];
     int front, rear, reply;
     int ch;
     front = rear = -1; //... Initialize a Queue
     printf("------------------------------\n");
     printf("\tMenu");
     printf("\n------------------------------");
     printf("\n 1. Insert String in a Queue");
     printf("\n 2. Delete String from a Queue");
     printf("\n 3. Exit");
     printf("\n------------------------------\n");
     while(1)
     {
           printf("Choose operation : ");
           scanf("%d", &ch);
           switch(ch)
           {
              case 1 : // insert
                    printf("\nEnter Something : ");
                    scanf("%s",data);
                    reply = insq(queue, &rear, data);
                    if(reply == -1 )
                          printf("\nQueue is Full \n");
                    else
                          printf("\n'%s' is inserted in queue.\n\n",data);
                    break;
              case 2 : // delete
                    reply = delq(queue, &front, &rear, data);
                    if( reply == -1 )
                          printf("\nQueue is Empty \n");
                    else
                          printf("\nDeleted String from Queue is : %s\n", data);
                          printf("\n");
                    break;
              case 3 : exit(0);
              default: printf("Invalid operation \n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please state an actual error, incorrect behaviour or question about the code. If it is not working as you intend then the thing to do is to debug it. Use a debugger to step through the code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Does `if( (data[]>='a' && data[]<='z'))` compile? You'll need to examine the input string character by character. It's also unclear why you need the 2D array when the task is to remember single characters.

Comment: @WeatherVane can you help me for all code?

Comment: Looking at the linked pseudo-code image, you might be interested in the function family `isalpha()` and `isspace()` and `ispunct()` etc.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with `queue` this is an array of 5 array of 80 chars.

Comment: actually i take this code any website and trying change.Sorry i usually used python in the school.This year we have to use c but i dont have any information @Ôrel

Comment: i will look @WeatherVane thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse char by char your string.
Test if it is an char with `isalpha` then do `toupper` and happen it to the buffer `out`. If not test for a blank char and copy it as it, finally just skip char.

Don't forget to add the final `\0`

/!\ A test if missing to check if you don't overflow `out`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    const char *p = "E)(=89y-/u665%P";
    char out[80];
    char *q = out;

    while (*p) {
        if (isalpha(*p)) {
            *q++ = toupper(*p++);
            continue;
        } else if (isblank(*p)) {
            *q++ = *p++;
            continue;
        }
        p++;
    }
    *q= '\0';
    printf("%s\n", out);

    return 0;
}
```

You have in out `"EYUP"`

Comment: i cant run this code. [Error] parameter 'p' is initialized

Comment: @EyüpŞirin I have added a full compiling code.

Comment: you are amazing thank you so much.How can I make this mixed input prompting the user? @Ôrel